# server sends back unwanted characters

Tags: c, sockets, winsock, winsock2

```
#include <io.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MY_PORT     8989
#define MAXBUF      256

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET sockfd ,clientfd; //define 2 sockets
    struct sockaddr_in self;
    char buffer[MAXBUF];

    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0){
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Initialised.\n");

    /*---create streaming socket---*/
    if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0 ){
        perror("Socket");
        exit(errno);
    }
    printf("Socket created.\n");

    /*---initialize address/port structure---*/
    /* bzero(&self, sizeof(self));*/
    self.sin_family = AF_INET;
    self.sin_port = htons(MY_PORT);
    self.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    /*---assign a port number to the socket---*/
    if ((bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&self, sizeof(self)))!=0){
        perror("socket--bind");
        exit(errno);
    }
    puts("Bind done");

    /*---make it a "listening socket"---*/
    if ((listen(sockfd, 20))!=0){
        perror("socket--listen");
        exit(errno);
    }
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");

    /*---forever... ---*/
    while (1){
        struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
        int addrlen=sizeof(client_addr);

        /*---accept a connection (creating a data pipe)---*/
        clientfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &addrlen);

        //create variables
        int length=recv(clientfd, buffer, MAXBUF, 0);

        //output in reverse order & lowercase
        for(int i=0; buffer[i]!='\0'; i++){
            if(buffer[i]>=65 && buffer[i]<=90){ // check ascii value
                buffer[i]= buffer[i]+32;       // if uppercase thn change
            }
        }

        int loop=0, len=strlen(buffer);
        char temp;  //temporary holds character to swap

        len--;     // remove null and start from 0

        while (loop<len){
            temp=buffer[loop];
            buffer[loop]=buffer[len];
            buffer[len]=temp;
            loop++;
            len--;
        }

        //send back
        send(clientfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);

        /*---close connection---*/
        close(clientfd);
    }

    /*---clean up (should never get here!)---*/
    close(sockfd);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

The reversing of string from client works well but it also gives out many other unwanted characters behind it and two 'PuTTy's, I'm very new to socket programming so any help is much appreciated. I can't use any string functions other than strlen. Currentlly using puTTy to open server on 8989. Telnet connection is passive.

Comment: Your posted code seems to be assuming that the client is sending a string terminated by a null character. Are you sure that the string is terminated by a null character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are ALWAYS sending MAXBUF (ie 256) bytes because in

```
send(clientfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
```

`sizeof(buffer)` is the size of the char array declared by

```
#define MAXBUF      256
char buffer[MAXBUF];
```

Fix this by using `strlen(buffer)` for example, or keeping the `len` you got previously.

Answer (score 1):

You code assumes that `buffer` is NUL terminated, however there is no guaranty that the NUL character will be received by `recv` (which may be a partial `recv` and this is streaming socket).

It would make more sense to reverse the data using the return value from `recv` (if a positive value). This way you do not have to worry about message boundaries.

```
    int length=recv(clientfd, buffer, MAXBUF, 0);

    //output in reverse order & lowercase
    for(int i=0; i < length; i++){
        if(buffer[i]>=65 && buffer[i]<=90){ // check ascii value
            buffer[i]= buffer[i]+32;       // if uppercase thn change
        }
    }
```

Comment: In the case of a partial `recv`, I believe it would make more sense to continue calling `recv` until all data has been received, and then to reverse the string.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel - this approach would depend the specification of the program, but since this example has no message protocol to define message boundaries, there is no way for the server to know if `recv` was partial or not...  it's a moot point.

Comment: There are at least two ways that could be used to determine when the message is complete: When the null character is encountered (if the server sends one) and when `read` returns `0` (assuming the server shuts down the connection). OP's posted code is looking for a null character, so it seems likely that the server is supposed to send such a null character. However, OP has not clearly stated this and has not responded to my request for clarification.